# Is this derivation of the Dirichlet Integral using a derivative under the integral sign, incorrect?

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, contour-integration, solution-verification, dirac-delta

To find the integral of the Sinc function:

Start with,
\begin{equation}
I(a)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\ ax }{x}dx %\hspace{20.0} ; (a>0)
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\Longrightarrow \frac{dI(a)}{da} = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\partial}{\partial a}(\frac{\sin\ ax}{x})dx= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \cos\ ax\ dx
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
      = \\ \textbf{Re}(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{iax} dx)=2\pi \delta(a)
\end{equation}

Take $a>0$; noting that $I(a)$ is an odd function, we get,
\begin{equation}
\Longrightarrow 2I(a)=\int_{-a}^{a}dI(a^{'})=2\pi \int_{-a}^{a} \delta(a^{'})da^{'}=2\pi
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
\Longrightarrow \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin\ x}{x}dx= \frac{1}{2}I(1)= \frac{\pi}{2}
\end{equation}
(The $a<0$ case following in a similar vein as well.)

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: I just realised now, that this paper existed! I'll not understand the mathematical justification given there. I trust that it's correct!

Comment: Awesome. If you have a chance you should take some higher-level math courses. It seems like they would suit you well.

Answer (score 0):

Since the integrand is even, we can reverse the order of integration. If you have learned laplace transforms, review the laplace transform of $\sin{x}$, or you can just integrate by parts. Whichever is easier for you. Next notice that  $\arctan(\infty)=\frac{\pi}{2}$
Lastly, use the fact below:
$$\int^\infty_0e^{-xt}dt=\frac{1}{x}$$
Therefore:
\begin{align}
 \tag1
&\int^\infty_{0}\frac{\sin{x}}{x}dx\\ \tag2
&=\int^\infty_0\int^\infty_0e^{-xt}\sin{x}dxdt\\ \tag3
&=\int^\infty_0\frac{1}{1+t^2}dt\\ \tag4
&=\frac{\pi}{2}
\end{align}

Additionally, the Dirichlet kernel converges to a Dirac delta function:
$$\lim_{a\to\infty}\frac{\sin(ax)}{x}=\frac\pi2 \delta(x).$$

Comment: I got $\frac{\pi}{2}$ for the integral from 0 to $\infty$, so I guess we agree. This seems good. But any comment on how the problematic cosine integral manages to give a correct answer in what I wrote?

Comment: @AritroPathak Sorry about that I noticed, I have changed my answer

Comment: @AritroPathak What exactly do you mean?

Comment: I saw your proof here: http://www.math.binghamton.edu/loya/papers/LoyaMathMag.pdf.

Comment: I meant, I can't understand how the diverging cosine integral, when written as the dirac delta function, gives the correct answer. That step should be problematic. I'm keen to know how that could be written in a mathematically rigorous way.

Comment: @AritroPathak Oh okay, I see...

Comment: @AritroPathak Well in physicist language, the Dirichlet kernel converges to a Dirac delta function:
$$\lim_{a\to\infty}\frac{\sin(ax)}{x}=\frac\pi2 \delta(x).$$