# Evaluate $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin s\cos s} s \,ds$ using $\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin s} s \, ds=\frac \pi 2$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, fourier-transform, integral-transforms

I got the answer $\frac{\pi}{4}$ by applying Fourier Integral Theorem but that didn't involve the given integral (although it did verify it). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1270448/is-this-derivation-of-the-dirichlet-integral-using-a-derivative-under-the-integr. This works with a=2.

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/272831) After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how it's supposed to work, I think:
$$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin s\cos s}{s}ds=\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin 2s}{2s}ds=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin s}{s}ds=\frac{\pi}{4}.$$